# VB 2019 - Populating unbound Column in DataGridView from another table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

So I know it is possible to just use the data adapters and sources to setup that unbound column gets populated with specific value from a linked reference table, but for some reason it is not working for me.

What other value do I need to set for the unbound column, clientReference

```
Public Class frmClientQuery
Private Sub clientsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clientsBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.clientsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me._30461723DataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_30461723DataSet.clientReferences' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.ClientReferencesTableAdapter.Fill(Me._30461723DataSet.clientReferences)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_30461723DataSet.clients' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.clientsTableAdapter.Fill(Me._30461723DataSet.clients)

    clientReference.DataPropertyName = "clientReferences.description"

End Sub End Class
```

DataTables:
[image]

Execution:
[image]

Comment: You are going about that the wrong way.  It shouldn't be an unbound column at all.  It should be a bound column for the `clientReferenceID` foreign key column.  You should make it a combo box column and then bind the second `DataTable` to it so that the `description` column values get displayed.  See [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476) for the how.

Comment: If you have your table adapters, etc, added to the form in the designer, you can set it all up there.  Simply edit the columns of the grid and change the type of that last column.  You can then set the `DataSource`, `DataMember`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the column as required.

Comment: @jmcilhinney please add these as an answer. Was so easy and quick to fix :)

Comment: My comments are to broad to constitute what I would consider a valid answer.  You should write your own answer that details the specifics of what you did based on my general comments.